# Can a URL have multiple parts of subdomain to it?

Tags: subdomain

I have a domain name abc.mydomain.com
This is a https URL ( http redirects to the https version )

However, I now need to be able to handle www.abc.mydomain.com to redirect to abc.mydomain.com

How can I do this? is it a webserver level redirect or something to be done at the DNS resolution.
I know my URL already has the "abc" as its sub-domain and I dont need a "www", however, we noticed that "www.news.google.com" resolves to "news.google.com" - hence wondering if I can achieve it too

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes.

DNS works on a hierarchy - the DNS server for .com can delegate down to the nameserver for your domain which *can* delegate further, or just answer the requests, which needs to be your first step.

If you use Bind style zone files, you *can* do something like (where `123.45.67.89` is your webserver IP address):

```
*    IN    A    123.45.67.89
```

Then, you *also* need your webserver to resolve that to the right virtual host/redirect as desired.

Comment: thanks for the response. So if i understand correclty, you are saying if there is an entry each for abc.mydomain.com and www.abc.mydomain.com in the zone file, the DNS look-up should work. and jsu for my info, how much further down can this delegation go? Also, does this mean no rewrite rules on my webserver would help me achieve this. I guess I understand teh flow once the request reaches the webserver, its just the VIP and DNS resolution part that i struggle with